# How to escape single quote in a string using .match method in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, escaping

My code is this:

```
description = contents.match(/===========(.*?)What's New in this Version/m)[1].strip
```

The code runs fine but now everything after the single quote is in blue and I need a single quote to end it. But where would I put it or how would I escape it? I tried putting a backslash before the single quote but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: The problem is with your editor's syntax highlighting. What editor are you using?

Comment: Yes you're right! I opened it in vim and everything is colour coded correctly. Now I just need to figure out how to change the settings in Xcode..

Comment: I suggest disabling silly colorization: it just makes code harder to read.

Comment: @tchrist: Intelligent colorization, on the other hand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work around the shortcomings of the Xcode syntax highlighter, you can replace the single quote with the octal escape code for that character:

```
/===========(.*?)What\047s New in this Version/m
```

PS. You can also shorten the start of your regex a bit:

```
/={11}(.*?)What\047s New in this Version/m
```

Answer (score 0):

You typically use the backslash "\" to escape special characters:

```
/===========(.*?)What\'s New in this Version/m
```

Comment: Like I said in the question, I tried that but it doesn't change anything. It doesn't close the single quote.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an XCode bug. You can try and get around it with this:

```
/===========(.*?)What.s New in this Version/m
# fix here ----------^
```